# BigQuery - incremental re-partition from ingest to business date in consumption layer

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm a newbie to BigQuery and trying to figure out a solution to this scenario:

- Transaction data is ingested to BQ table that is partitioned on ingest_date
- Business key for a transaction is trade_id but a transaction can also have versions so business key for a record is trade_id + trade_version
- There may be duplicates on business key so the technical key is trade_id + trade_version_id + ingest_timestamp
- Transaction contains a business timestamp when it was actually executed but this may differ from ingestion timestamp as data may arrive late up to several days or weeks
- The data is to be enriched and transformed in several steps and finally end up in a table available for consumption downstream
- Consumption table must be partitioned on business date for good performance on filtering and also contain a flag to enable filtering on latest version only

Have googled quite a lot on this but haven't seen any clear solution or pattern to use so I did some elaboration on my own and came up with a solution that it would be great to get some reviews and comments on (not 100% sure it works).

Also read briefly about DBT and Dataform, have these tools automated solutions to this?

Here it is:

---

The small data model I've worked with: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1baT.jpg

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
-- Table DDL's

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `<dataset>.raw`
(
    raw_key STRING,
    ingest_date DATE,
    ingest_timestamp TIMESTAMP,
    trade_id STRING,
    trade_version STRING,
    business_date DATE,
    business_timestamp TIMESTAMP
)
PARTITION BY ingest_date
OPTIONS (
    require_partition_filter=true
)

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `<dataset>.partition_ingest2business`
(
  ingest_date DATE,
  business_date DATE,
  ingest_timestamp TIMESTAMP
)

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `<dataset>.consume`
(
  trade_id STRING,
  trade_version STRING,
  business_date DATE,
  latest_version BOOL,
  raw_key STRING,
  ingest_date DATE,
  version_desc INT64
)
PARTITION BY business_date
OPTIONS (
  require_partition_filter=true
)

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `<dataset>.consume_ctrl`
(
  partition_ingest_timestamp TIMESTAMP
)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
-- Some test data
/*
delete from <dataset>.raw where ingest_date > '1899-01-01';
delete from <dataset>.transform where ingest_date > '1899-01-01';
delete from <dataset>.partition_ingest2business where ingest_date > '1899-01-01';
*/

insert into <dataset>.raw select 'raw_key_001', cast('2000-01-01' as date), cast('2000-01-01 00:00:01' as timestamp), 'trade_id_001', 'trade_version_001_01', cast('2000-01-01' as date),  cast('2000-01-01 00:00:01' as timestamp);
insert into <dataset>.raw select 'raw_key_002', cast('2000-01-01' as date), cast('2000-01-01 00:00:02' as timestamp), 'trade_id_002', 'trade_version_002_01', cast('2000-01-01' as date),  cast('2000-01-01 00:00:02' as timestamp);
insert into <dataset>.raw select 'raw_key_003', cast('2000-01-03' as date), cast('2000-01-03 00:00:01' as timestamp), 'trade_id_003', 'trade_version_003_01', cast('2000-01-03' as date),  cast('2000-01-03 00:00:01' as timestamp);
insert into <dataset>.raw select 'raw_key_004', cast('2000-01-03' as date), cast('2000-01-03 00:00:02' as timestamp), 'trade_id_004', 'trade_version_004_01', cast('2000-01-03' as date),  cast('2000-01-03 00:00:02' as timestamp);
insert into <dataset>.raw select 'raw_key_005', cast('2000-01-03' as date), cast('2000-01-03 00:00:03' as timestamp), 'trade_id_005', 'trade_version_005_01', cast('2000-01-03' as date),  cast('2000-01-03 00:00:03' as timestamp);
insert into <dataset>.raw select 'raw_key_006', cast('2000-01-03' as date), cast('2000-01-03 00:00:04' as timestamp), 'trade_id_006', 'trade_version_006_01', cast('2000-01-03' as date),  cast('2000-01-03 00:00:04' as timestamp);

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
-- Incremental load of partition_ingest2business table

declare max_ingest_timestamp timestamp default
(
select max(ingest_timestamp)
from <dataset>.partition_ingest2business
);

if max_ingest_timestamp is null then
  -- Destination table is empty, set partiton filer from source table
  set max_ingest_timestamp = cast('1899-01-01' as timestamp);
end if;

select max_ingest_timestamp, cast(max_ingest_timestamp as date);

select 
   ingest_date
  ,business_date
 ,max(ingest_timestamp)
from <dataset>.raw
where 
      ingest_date       >= cast(max_ingest_timestamp as date)
group by   
   ingest_date
  ,business_date;

-- Merge into destination table
merge <dataset>.partition_ingest2business trgt
using
  ( 
    select 
       ingest_date
      ,business_date
      ,max(ingest_timestamp) as ingest_timestamp
    from <dataset>.raw
    where 
          ingest_date       >= cast(max_ingest_timestamp as date)
      and ingest_timestamp  >  max_ingest_timestamp
    group by   
      ingest_date
     ,business_date
  ) src

on trgt.ingest_date = src.ingest_date and trgt.business_date = src.business_date
when not matched then
  insert(ingest_date, business_date, ingest_timestamp) values (src.ingest_date, src.business_date, src.ingest_timestamp)

when matched and trgt.ingest_timestamp != src.ingest_timestamp then
  update set ingest_timestamp = src.ingest_timestamp;

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
-- Incremental load of consume table with partition overwrite

declare ingest_date_filter array<date>;
declare business_date_filter array<date>;

declare partition_ingest_timestamp timestamp default
  (
    select partition_ingest_timestamp
    from <dataset>.consume_ctrl
  );

declare max_ingest_timestamp timestamp default
  (
    select max(ingest_timestamp)
    from <dataset>.partition_ingest2business
  );

if partition_ingest_timestamp is null then 
  set partition_ingest_timestamp = cast('1899-01-01' as timestamp);
  insert into <dataset>.consume_ctrl (partition_ingest_timestamp) values (cast('1899-01-01' as timestamp));
end if;

set business_date_filter =
  (
    select ARRAY_AGG(distinct business_date)
    from <dataset>.partition_ingest2business
    where 
          ingest_timestamp >  partition_ingest_timestamp
      and ingest_timestamp <= max_ingest_timestamp
  );      

set ingest_date_filter =
  (
    select ARRAY_AGG(distinct ingest_date)
    from <dataset>.partition_ingest2business
    where business_date in UNNEST(business_date_filter)
  );      

if ARRAY_LENGTH(business_date_filter) > 0 then 
  merge <dataset>.consume trgt using
  (
    select 
       trade_id
      ,trade_version
      ,business_date
      ,row_number() over (partition by trade_id order by trade_version desc, business_timestamp desc, ingest_timestamp desc) as version_desc
      ,raw_key
      ,ingest_date
    from <dataset>.raw
    where 
          ingest_date in unnest(ingest_date_filter)
      and ingest_timestamp <= max_ingest_timestamp
  ) src
  on false

  when not matched and business_date in unnest(business_date_filter) then
    insert(trade_id, trade_version, business_date, version_desc, raw_key, ingest_date)  values(trade_id, trade_version, business_date, version_desc, raw_key, ingest_date)

  when not matched by source and business_date in unnest(business_date_filter) then 
    delete;

  -- Update consume_ctrl with max_ingest_timestamp to be used next execution
  update <dataset>.consume_ctrl set partition_ingest_timestamp = max_ingest_timestamp where 1 = 1;

end if;
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't asked a specific question(s) but some responses...

As you are aware I think, you are using standard partitioning not ingestion-time partitioning which would look like this...
PARTITION BY _PARTITIONDATE

I am a bit wary of row level operations like merge on BigQuery on big fact tables although performance improvements have been released in recent months. Analytical columnar databases generally excel in append rather than merge use cases

Due to currently limitations of BigQuery materialized views (partitioning must be same as underlying table) you do indeed need separate tables if you wish to have both PARTITION BY ingest_date and business_date tables available

For .consume you could add clustering, it does have performance/on-demand cost benefits, sometimes massive query cost reductions depending on cardinality of the chosen columns
PARTITION BY business_date
CLUSTER BY latest_version

I'm more familiar with Dataform (than DBT) which does not automate complex transformations except where Packages are provided and/or you write your own in javascript. Here is a link explaining how to solve a common complex transformation problem SCD's by utilising a SCD package provided by dataform

https://docs.dataform.co/packages/dataform-scd

Dataform is excellent for refactoring/documentation/assertions/testing/deployment SQL tranforms (using SQLX). New Dataform Cloud users are put on a waitlist since May 12 after acquistion by GCP however you can still install Dataform and use Dataform CLI.